# Pass optional multiple arguments to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

This might be a duplicate but I had little success in finding the right answer. I'm trying to achieve something like this :

```
var joinArrays = function(myCollectionOfArguments) {
    return array.concat(array1, array2, ..... , arrayN);
};
```

In which case `myCollectionOfArguments` will be `array1, array2, ..... , arrayN`. How could I achieve something like that ? I do know that if I had a callback function I cold pass as many arguments as I would like using `.apply()`, but in this certain case I'm a bit confused on the approach.

**EDIT :** So, to be more descriptive : Instead of passing just one argument, I would to be able to pass as many as I want without having to specify it when I define the function's arguments, in my case `myCollectionOfArguments`, would be just one argument when defining the function, but when I want to use the function I want to be able to pass more than one argument ;

Comment: Why do you think you would need a callback function for [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)? Show us how you tried to use it; an example invocation of `joinArrays` could help as well

Comment: "something like this" is actually not descriptive enough.

Comment: So, to be more descriptive : Instead of passing just one argument, I would to be able to pass as many as I want without having to specify it when I define the function's arguments, in my case `myCollectionOfArguments`, would be just one argument when defining the function, but when I want to use the function I want to be able to pass more than one argument ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your intention right, try:

```
var joinArrays = function(a) {
  return a.concat.apply(a, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};

var foo = joinArrays([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]);

console.log(foo); // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Why use one explicit parameter? (OK, you could also join strings with that, but…)

Comment: @Bergi ~ I have no idea :)) I just realized that I don't need one, just that it tells me that it accepts arguments I guess

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for an arbitrary amount of arguments, and you can even pass that directly into [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var joinArrays = function() {
    return [].concat.apply([], arguments);
};
```

Btw, using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) would be more elegant here:

```
var joinArrays = Array.prototype.concat.bind([]);
```

Comment: Bind is ECMAScript 5 though, ya? Not compatible with older browsers if that's something to consider.

Comment: Yeah, but easy and uncomplicated to shim. My motto: Use it without caution, and simply add the polyfill if someone complains :-) Browsers lacking support for it are the minority today.

Comment: Depends on the website or application. I worked at Dictionary.com last year and still over 60% of their traffic came from IE8. While `bind` is more elegant, your ECMAScript 4 solution is only a few more characters so in this case I wouldn't even think to use `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function testFunction()
{
    var arg1 = arguments[0];
    var arg2 = arguments[1];
    var arg3 = arguments[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but you can pass arbitrary number of arrays:

```
joinArrays([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8], [9,10,11,12])
```

and later read all of them using special `arguments` variable inside `joinArrays()`.